# Prove any orthogonal 2-by-2 can be written in one of these forms....

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I'd like to prove that any orthogonal $2 \times 2$ matrix can be written

$$\bigg(\begin{matrix}
   \cos x & -\sin x  \\ 
   \sin x & \cos x  
\end{matrix}\bigg) \hspace{1.0em} \text{or} \hspace{1.0em}
\bigg(\begin{matrix}
   \cos x & \sin x \\
   \sin x & -\cos x
\end{matrix}\bigg)$$ 
for $0 \le x < 2\pi$.

I have no idea how to do this. I feel like this is something I've missed and is really straightforward but I can't find it in my book...

Comment: Welcome to MSE, please use  [MathJAx](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference)  for typing your question.

Comment: I don't know mathjax, can't I wrap the TeX in some tags so that it will render?

Comment: Please check this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-qu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bick-reference.

Comment: Thank-you, I will use both to learn mathjax.

Comment: This is a simple change of basis. Both matrices you gave are orthogonal, which means you can map ANY point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using it! Thus, any other orthogonal base you choose in $\mathbb{R}^2$, can be rewritten using some this two basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ be orthogonal, then we have $MM^T=I_2$ and thus
$$\begin{cases}a^2+b^2=1 \\ c^2+d^2 = 1 \\ac+bd=0\end{cases}$$
By the $2$ first equations, we know that there exists $\theta,\phi\in [0,2\pi)$ such that 
$$ a = \cos(\theta), \quad b = \sin(\theta),\quad c = \sin(\phi), \quad d = \cos(\phi).$$
To convince you of this fact, think that the vectors $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ in $\Bbb R^2$ are lying on the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^2$.
Now, the last equation implies
$$\sin(\theta+\phi)=\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi)+\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi)=0,$$
where we used an [angle sum identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for the sinus.
Now, $\sin(\theta+\phi)=0$ implies that $\theta +\phi= k\pi$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$ because $\sin(0)=0$ and the [periodicity of the sinus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity). In particular, since $\theta,\phi\in [0,2\pi)$, we have $\phi = -\theta + \delta \pi$ with $\delta\in\{0,1\}$.

Now, [note that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Shifts_and_periodicity)
$$ \sin(\delta\pi-\theta)=(-1)^{1-\delta}\sin(\theta) \quad \text{and}  \quad\cos(\delta\pi-\theta)=(-1)^{\delta}\cos(\theta)\quad \text{for}\quad \delta \in\{0,1\}.$$

- If $\delta=0$, we get $\phi=-\theta$ and therefore

$$ a=\cos(\theta)=\cos(-\theta)=d \qquad \text{and}\qquad b=\sin(\theta)=-\sin(\phi)=-c.$$

- If $\delta=1$, we get $\phi=\pi-\theta$ and therefore

$$ a=\cos(\theta)=-\cos(\pi-\theta)=-d \;\text{and}\;b=\sin(\theta)=\sin(\pi-\phi)=c.$$

Comment: At last, I see where the trig functions come in. I'm afraid I can't take it from there though, is this a trig manipulation thing? I see how the entries can be trig functions including negative ones (since they're being squared) but I don't see why it has to be those configurations specifically. Actually, I am confused by the last equation. How can $\theta  = \phi $ (as it is in the configurations from the book, the angle is always the same) when ${\sin ^2}x + {\cos ^2}x = 1$?

Comment: @CoffeeToTheorems I edited my answer. Is it more clear to you know?

Comment: No, honestly I'm more confused. I'm really struggling with matrices and so-on, I'm not used to struggling with math. I'm not sure I'm going to be able to get this...

Comment: @CoffeeToTheorems Is it better now?

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer, I'm still going to have to go over it a few times but yes, I think so.

Comment: @CoffeeToTheorems you're welcome :). Just post a comment here if you're still puzzled about something.

Comment: I understand everything until the last part where we take the two possible values of $\delta $
It seems that, for instance, when it's 0 then b = $\sin \theta $ instead of $ - \sin \theta $
If $\delta $ = 0 is the second matrix then it still doesn't make sense because both a and d would be $\cos \theta $ but d is negative.

Comment: @CoffeeToTheorems $\delta =0$ corresponds to the first matrix and $b=\sin(\theta) = -\sin(-\theta) =-\sin(\phi)=-c$. So, actually this shows that $M^T$ has the form of the first matrix which is enough. if you really want the expression for $M$ instead of $M^T$ just take $\tilde \theta = 2\pi-\theta$ instead of $\theta$ and then you'll get that $M$ is of the form of the first matrix.