# Set of orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices

Tags: orthogonality

I need to do a proof for a paper, and I need to make sure of something. Is it true that the full set of orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices can be represented by:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}$$

or are there other possible rotations not accounted by this representation?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All rotations of the plane have this form, but the set of orthogonal matrices also contains axial symmetries, who have determinant $-1$. You need to add the matrices of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) 
  \\ \sin(\theta) &-\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}.$$
For a proof that any orthogonal matrice has one of these forms, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574918/prove-any-orthogonal-2-by-2-can-be-written-in-one-of-these-forms).

Comment: Many thanks! Then I will do the proof with both possibilities!

Comment: @Chucky After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: One should add that the first category constitute the family of rotations, and the second one (given by @Arnaud D.) corresponds to (orthogonal ) reflections (i.e., symmetries).